# .NET MAUI Template project fails to debug on windows

Tags: .net, maui, .net-maui

Following the tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/first-app?pivots=devices-windows). I cannot get the default project to run or debug. Upon pushing the debug "play" button, I get this error after it is done building:
[image: error]

For the bots: Error says "Unable to activate Windows Store app {XxXxXxX} The activation request failed with error "The process has no package identity."

Comment: Are you on Windows 10 version 1809 or higher, or Windows 11? [Supported platforms](https://github.com/dotnet/docs-maui/blob/main/docs/supported-platforms.md). If so, and you updated from earlier VS Preview versions, Uninstall VS Preview, reboot pc, install the latest 2022 Preview, and create a new project from scratch using the Maui project template.

Comment: Windows 10 build 19044 as best I can tell.

Comment: That's fine. I'm on OS build 19043. And have never seen that error for Maui. Consider that project corrupted; start over.

Comment: The same error occurs each time a new project is created.

Comment: Something must be corrupted. Did you uninstall VS Preview, reboot pc, reinstall?  ALSO google `windows store allow apps not from store` - maybe store is somehow interfering.